# Way to logout/restart to another operating system

Tags: 11.10

In some computers that also have Windows XP or Windows 7 I normally reboot the PC and from the GRUB menu select Windows if I want to boot to it or just leave it alone to start with Ubuntu. I am trying to find a way to, for example, when telling Ubuntu to restart it gives me a choice to restart with another operating system without having to be there when the grub menu appears. Like a temporary option that boots to Windows, Mac or another Linux Distro for that time. Something like a "quick OS switcher".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `grub-reboot`.

grub-reboot sets the default boot entry for GRUB, for the next boot only.

```
grub-reboot ENTRY
```

ENTRY is a number or a menu item title.

See `man grub-reboot` for more info.